# Reload UIViewController and xib

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, xcode4

I have an app that has a MyViewController with two subclasses, MyViewControllerMain and MyViewControllerSettings.

In MyViewControllerSettings, I allow the user to change the font, color, etc.  How do I instruct MyViewControllerMain to refresh itself so the changes show up?

Thanks,
Tony

Here is what I am doing:

```
I initialize it in viewDidLoad of my superclass like this:

m_fFontSize = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) ? 28 : 16;
m_MyFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Greg's Hand" size:m_fFontSize];
```

And then in derived settings class, I do this:

```
NSString * sFont = [fontList objectAtIndex:row];
m_MyFont = [UIFont fontWithName:sFont size:m_fFontSize];
```

And in my dervied MainView class in viewWillAppear, I do this:

```
tfName.font = m_MyFont;
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends - if you have, say, a UILabel, UIButton or the like in your MyViewControllerMain and you change their font / color, they *should* update themselves (make sure you really set the font, color, etc!).

Otherwise, you can always try `[[myViewController view] setNeedsDisplay]`.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to redraw the whole view using your settings.

For each & every time, method name:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];

           //Over here just set the font size of all the controllers you are using.
            This will definitely solve your problem since this method is called every time before the View Appears.
    }
```

Comment: Ajay, I tried that and it did not seem to work.  I have a member variable with my font and in the settings page I change that member variable to the new font.  When I go back to the main page viewWillAppear does get called and I am performing: textField.font = m_MyFont, but it does not change the font.  Any ideas?

Comment: Does you member variable m_MyFont retain the updated value ???Just try to print in ViewWillAppear & one more thing please make sure that you are not setting the font size any where else too ..in same class.